# Variable not being properly assigned inside of a for loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm measuring the height of UI components being generated during runtime. Height(i) only returns 100. So what it should return is -100 + Index. But for some reason, any index over 0 returns -100.

```
    public float ComponentPos (int Index) {
        float Pos = 0;
        Debug.Log(Index);
        for (int i = 0; i < Index; i++) {
            Pos = Pos - Height(i);
            Debug.Log(i + ": " + Height(i));
            Debug.Log("Pos: " + Pos);
        }
        
        return Pos;
    }
```

I debugged using Debug.Log, it shows that it counts the height of the 0th component and 1st component as 100. But then the value of Pos is only -100. I have no idea why it only does the subtraction once. The result is the same no matter how many times I call this function. Any index over 0 returns -100.

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VnCL.png)

Edit: Ma3x gave me a solution

```
 public float ComponentPos (int Index) {
        float Pos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Index; i++) {
            float h = Height(i); 
            Pos = Pos - h;
        }        
        return Pos;
 }
```

Also here is the code for Height(i)

```
 public float Height(int Index) {
        return AbilityTypeWindows[AbilityType.text].GetChild(Index).GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height;
 }
```

It's very ugly and long, but basically it returns the height value of a UI component.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Oh thank you I didn't think of doing that for some reason.

Comment: Can you please change the first 2 lines inside the `for` loop to these 3 lines `float h = Height(i); Pos = Pos - h; Debug.Log(i + ": " + h);` and check if you get the same log output?

Comment: Hey that worked! Could you explain why? Maybe I'm unaware of some kind of C# quirk.

Comment: I am glad it worked, but it sounds like a bug that needs fixing. Please post the contents of your `Height(...)` method.

Comment: I just edited the post for you.

Comment: Thanks. Well I am glad that it works now, but it is worrying that repeated calls to the `Height(i)` method produced different results before with 2 calls per loop than now with just one call per loop. Now seeing the Height method I don't know why that would be the case. Well if it works consistently now, then keep it like this, hopefully you don't run into problems when you will increase the index or something.